# How to manage state of two different stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The basic outline of the widget is shown Below. *MyListViewBuilder1* and *MyListViewBuilder2* both *stateful* widget are defined in separate dart file. Both of them consists of ListViewBuilder.

What I want to achieve is that when the item of **MyListViewBuilder1** gets deleted then deleted item appears in **MyListViewBuilder2**, But the problem is  this happens only when I restart the screen. 
So how can I change solve this?

How can I change the state of next when state of one is changed?

```
Column(
children: <Widget>[
MyListViewBuilder1(),
MyListViewBuilder2()
  ]
)
```

Comment: How you are passing the list?  can you show it?

Comment: @jitsm555 Both MyListViewBuilder1/2 gets data from SQLite and generates Lists individually

Comment: So basically you are deleting item from MyListViewBuilder1() widget & you want to reflect your changes in MyListViewBuilder2() widget. is this right?

Comment: The easiest way to maintain state is to use provider package .

Comment: @jitsm555 yes the reflection should be instant. Not after relaunching screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to manage state in different widgets throughout the application. In the below example, when an item is deleted in the `MyListViewBuilder1`, it is removed from the list and added to the list of deleted items in the `ItemChangeNotifier` class. The `MyListViewBuilder2` has its own independent list of items, however in its `build` method it watches for any changes to the list of deleted items in the `ItemChangeNofifier` class and adds these deleted items to its own independent list of items.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ItemChangeNotifier>(
          create: (context) {
            return ItemChangeNotifier();
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class Item {
  int id;
  String title;

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.title,
  });
}

class ItemChangeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _deletedItems = <Item>[];

  List<Item> get deletedItems => List.unmodifiable(_deletedItems);

  void deleteItem(Item item) {
    _deletedItems.add(item);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: MyListViewBuilder1(),
          ),
          Divider(
            thickness: 8,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: MyListViewBuilder2(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListViewBuilder1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListViewBuilder1State createState() => _MyListViewBuilder1State();
}

class _MyListViewBuilder1State extends State<MyListViewBuilder1> {
  List<Item> _items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(_items[index].title),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<ItemChangeNotifier>().deleteItem(_items[index]);

              setState(() {
                _items.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: _items.length,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _items = List.generate(
      10,
      (index) => Item(
        id: index + 1,
        title: 'Item ${index + 1}',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListViewBuilder2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListViewBuilder2State createState() => _MyListViewBuilder2State();
}

class _MyListViewBuilder2State extends State<MyListViewBuilder2> {
  List<Item> _items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = [
      ..._items,
      ...context.select<ItemChangeNotifier, List<Item>>(
        (itemChangeNotifier) => itemChangeNotifier.deletedItems,
      ),
    ];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(items[index].title),
        );
      },
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _items = List.generate(
      10,
      (index) => Item(
        id: index + 101,
        title: 'Item ${index + 101}',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```